# Why are these Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 publishers in Russian?

Tags: windows-10, control-panel, software-update

The publisher of many of these Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 and 2013 Redistributable packages is in Russian:

[image: Unknown Publisher for MS C++ 2013]

Why is this?

Comment: The publisher it shows is just Microsoft Corporation written in Russian. Have a look at [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/found-kop%D0%BFopa%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/e2c732d1-af59-4232-9839-eddb65e90fad).

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ redistributable and runtime packages are mostly installed for standard libraries that many applications use. Some are installed along with Windows itself. Any additional versions of the Visual C++ Redistributable you see on your system were installed along with some program that required it. A malware program may have a fake version of Visual C++ Redistributable bundled with it, so that when you install the malware, you also install the fake Visual C++ Redistributable program.

In the Windows Event Viewer you can find a list of installed applications. Search Event Viewer to find out which programs were installed at the same time as the Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 and 2013 Redistributable packages in Russian. Then search for the program(s) online to find out if there are any reports of any of them being malicious software.

1. To launch the Event Viewer, type *Event Viewer* in the Start menu search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. In the tree in the left pane of Event Viewer, click *Application*.
3. Filter by Event ID to see specific types of events. MSI (Windows Installer) files will write entries to the Windows event log. Other installers may or may not. Installation and uninstallation activity is identified in the Event Viewer by a MsiInstaller entry. [Event ID 1033  from MsiInstaller](https://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-1033-source-MsiInstaller-eventno-10808-phase-1.htm) indicates that an attempt to install a product was initiated.

Comment: There is no evidence that those installations are fraudulent...